# JSON array returned to Android is not having complete data

Tags: android, json

I'm working on a PHP, Laravel and Android application.

Laravel provides all the JSON data from server (a website is also required) and Android app is the consumer.

I'm trying to read all groups of a user with the following function:

```
public function dataAllGroups($id)
{
    if(isset($id)){

        $user = User::find($id);

        if(isset($user)){
            $groups = UserGroup::where('status', '=', 'active')->where('user_id', $id)->get();

            $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
            $last_query = end($queries);

            if(isset($groups) && count($groups)>0)
                return array('message' => 'found', 'groups' => $groups, 'count' => count($groups), 'query' => $last_query);
            else
                return array('message' => 'empty', 'query' => $last_query);
        }
        else
            return array('message' => 'invalid');
    }
    else
        return array();
}
```

This returns following in logcat

```
05-11 09:04:14.646    2531-2554/com.activetasks.activetasks D/group read result﹕ {"message":"found","groups":{},"count":2,"query":{"query":"select * from `user_groups` where `status` = ? and `user_id` = ?","bindings":["active","14"],"time":1}}
```

So, the query is correct, count says I'm getting 2 records but groups says {}

This is a bit weird for me.

This is my Android logic for reading JSON array:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String result = null;

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

        try{

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            result = builder.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And here I read the returned groups:

```
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("groups");

                for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Group group = new Group();

                    group.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
                    group.setName(json_data.getString("name"));

                    groups.add(group);
                }

                groupAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: `groups` is your `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

Comment: Hi Piyush, thanks for the quick reply. I'm expecting a number of groups to be returned. If it is a JSON object, then how should I read array out of it? Also, why groups is {}?

Comment: But where is the array?? `]` this represents as a `JSONArray`.

Comment: Please also post JSON data you are getting from server.

Comment: @SachinGupta You can see in logcat

Comment: Hi Piyush, I already posted the JSON result above: "This returns following in logcat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed the code to:

'groups' => $groups->toArray()

and I'm getting groups data.

Answer (score 0):

`groups` is your `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

You need to change from

```
 JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("groups");
```

to

```
 JSONObject Jb= json.getJSONObject("groups");
```